# Laravel Product Filter by Price

Tags: php, html, laravel

I have a filter route to filter my products by brand & weight & count and taste and all are working fine but when i want to add a sort filter its not working, i want to sort it by pirce ( Ascending and descending).
here is my codes
***Route:***

```
Route::match(['get', 'post'], 'products/filter', [SearchController::class, 'filterall']);
```

***SearchController:***

```
 public function filterall(Request $request){
        $data = $request->all();
//        echo "<pre>"; print_r($data);
        $brandUrl = "";
        $weightUrl = "";
        $countUrl = "";
        $tasteUrl = "";
        $sortUrl = "";
        if(!empty($data['brandFilter'])){
            foreach ($data['brandFilter'] as $brand){
                if(empty($brandUrl)){
                    $brandUrl = "&brand=".$brand;
                }else{
                    $brandUrl .= "-".$brand;
                }
            }
        }

        if(!empty($data['weightFilter'])){
            foreach ($data['weightFilter'] as $weight){
                if(empty($weightUrl)){
                    $weightUrl = "&weight=".$weight;
                }else{
                    $weightUrl .= "-".$weight;
                }
            }
        }

        if(!empty($data['countFilter'])){
            foreach ($data['countFilter'] as $count){
                if(empty($countUrl)){
                    $countUrl = "&count=".$count;
                }else{
                    $countUrl .= "-".$count;
                }
            }
        }

        if(!empty($data['tasteFilter'])){
            foreach ($data['tasteFilter'] as $taste){
                if(empty($tasteUrl)){
                    $tasteUrl = "&taste=".$taste;
                }else{
                    $tasteUrl .= "-".$taste;
                }
            }
        }


        if(!empty($data['sort'])){
            foreach ($data['sort'] as $sort){
                if(empty($sortUrl)){
                    $sortUrl = "&sort=".$sort;
                }else{
                    $sortUrl .= "-".$sort;
                }
            }
        }



        $finalUrl = "category/".$data['url_id'].'/'.$data['url_slug']."?".$brandUrl.$weightUrl.$countUrl.$tasteUrl.$sortUrl;
        return redirect::to($finalUrl);
    }
```

*** My View Controller ***

```
public function allCategory(Request $request, $id){
        $catt = DB::table('categories')->where('id', $id)->first();
        $products = Product::where('category_id', $catt->id)->where('status', '1')
            ->orderBy('brand_id', 'ASC');

        if(!empty($_GET['brand'])){
            $brandArray = explode('-', $_GET['brand']);
            $products = $products->whereIn('brand_id', $brandArray);
        }

        if(!empty($_GET['weight'])){
            $weightArray = explode('-', $_GET['weight']);
            $products = $products->whereIn('product_weight', $weightArray);
        }

        if(!empty($_GET['count'])){
            $countArray = explode('-', $_GET['count']);
            $products = $products->whereIn('product_count', $countArray);
        }

        if(!empty($_GET['taste'])){
            $tasteArray = explode(',', $_GET['taste']);
            foreach ($tasteArray as $taste){
                $products = $products->where('product_taste','LIKE', "%$taste%");
            }

            if(!empty($_GET['sort'])){
                $sortArray = explode('-', $_GET['sort']);
                $products = $products->orderBy('selling_price', $sortArray);
            }


        }

        $products = $products->paginate(12);

        return view('pages.all_category', compact('products', 'catt'));
    }
```

and this is the view code:

```
 <div class="row" id="search-results">
                        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12">
                            <div class="toolbar toolbar-products">
                                <div class="toolbar-sorter sorter">
                                    <label class="sorter-label" for="sort">Sort By</label>
                                    @if(!empty($_GET['sort']))
                                        <?php $sortArray = explode('-', $_GET['sort']) ?>
                                    @endif
                                    <select id="sort" name="sort[]" class="sorter-options" onchange="javascript:this.form.submit();">
                                        <option value="">Select</option>
                                        @if(!empty($_GET['sort']))
                                            <?php $price = $_GET['sort'] ?>
                                        @endif
                                        <option value="ASC" @if(!empty($sortArray) && in_array('ASC', $sortArray)) selected="" @endif>Lowest Price</option>

                                        <option value="DESC" @if(!empty($sortArray) && in_array('DESC', $sortArray)) selected="" @endif>Highest Price</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

im doing this by Form in page.
I think orderBy in front Controller is not working is there other way to sort that?

Comment: second parameter of orderBy takes direction to sort results it can be asc or desc but you are passing an array `$sortArray` what are the contents of `$sortArray` can you print this array and show us the output

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid the outpout of that array is ASC or DESC and i also checked it by writing ASC and DESC directly but it didnt work

Comment: Not sure but I guess you need to clear previous order by criteria  before you apply order by price like `$products->reorder('selling_price', $sortDir)`

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid thank you for following up but it didnt worked for me and still have this problem

Comment: guys please help me, orderBy is not working for sort products by price

Comment: There might be one issue that I can see is your sorting snippet is inside `if(!empty($_GET['taste'])){` so when taste is empty your sorting code is not executed, can try moving the sort part outside if taste's if clause

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid Thank you so much yes actually that was the problem and i don't know why made that mistake by the way thanks for giving time and solving my problem you are awesome